# Unix shell's input redirection not working

Tags: c, shell, unix, io-redirection

I found the same question but there was no answer.

In building my own unix shell, my output redirection is working fine, but when I try the input it does not do anything. If you could help me figure out the problem that would be great.
This is my exec function code:

```
void execute (char **args)
{
   int pid, status;
   pid = fork ();

   if (pid < 0) 
   {
      perror ("Error forking!");
      return;
   }


   else if (pid > 0) 
   {
      fflush(0);
      while (wait (&status) != pid)
         continue;
   }


   else if (pid == 0) 
   {

      int i,in=0,out=0;
      char input[BUF_SIZE],output[BUF_SIZE];

      for(i=0;args[i]!=NULL;i++)
      {
         if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0)
         {        
            args[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(input,args[i+1]);
            in=2;           
         }               

         if(strcmp(args[i],">")==0)
         {      
            args[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(output,args[i+1]);
            out=2;
         }         
      }


      if(in)
      {   
         int fd0;
         if ((fd0 = open(input, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0) 
         {
            perror("Couldn't open input file");
            exit(0);
         }           

         dup2(fd0, 0); 

         close(fd0); 
      }


      if (out)
      {
         int fd1;
         if ((fd1 = creat(output , 0644)) < 0) 
         {
            perror("Couldn't open the output file");
            exit(0);
         }           

         dup2(fd1, 1); 
         close(fd1);
      }

      execvp (*args, args);
      perror("execvp");
      _exit(1);
   }
```

Here is my whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define ARGSIZE 20
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

void execute (char **args);
void cd (char *directory);
int killpid (char *pitstr, int sig);

int main (void)
{
    char line[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    char *args[ARGSIZE] = {NULL};
    char *token;
    int i, argIndex = 0;

    while (1) 
    {

        argIndex = 0; 

        for (i = 0; i < ARGSIZE; i++)
            args[i] = NULL;

        printf ("shell> "); 

        if (fgets (line, BUF_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) 
        {
            printf ("EOF received\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if (*line == '\n') 
        continue;

        token = strtok (line, " \n"); 

        while (token != NULL) 
        {
            args[argIndex] = token;
            token = strtok (NULL, " \n");
            argIndex++;
        }

        if (!argIndex)
            continue;  

        if (strcmp (args[0], "quit") == 0 || strcmp (args[0], "exit") == 0)
            break;

        if ((strcmp (args[0], "cd") == 0))
            cd (args[1]);
        else if ((strcmp (args[0], "kill") == 0)) 
        {
            if (args[1])
                killpid (args[1], SIGTERM);
        }


        else
            execute (args);

    }
    return 0;
}

void execute (char **args)
{
    int pid, status;
    pid = fork ();

    if (pid < 0) 
    {
        perror ("Error forking!");
        return;
    }


    else if (pid > 0) 
    {
        fflush(0);
        while (wait (&status) != pid)
            continue;
    }


    else if (pid == 0) 
    {

        int i,in=0,out=0;
        char input[BUF_SIZE],output[BUF_SIZE];

        for(i=0;args[i]!=NULL;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0)
            {        
                args[i]=NULL;
                strcpy(input,args[i+1]);
                in=2;           
            }               

            if(strcmp(args[i],">")==0)
            {      
                args[i]=NULL;
                strcpy(output,args[i+1]);
                out=2;
            }         
        }


        if(in)
        {   
            int fd0;
            if ((fd0 = open(input, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0) 
            {
                perror("Couldn't open input file");
                exit(0);
            }           

            dup2(fd0, 0); 
            close(fd0); 
        }


        if (out)
        {
            int fd1;
            if ((fd1 = creat(output , 0644)) < 0) 
            {
                perror("Couldn't open the output file");
                exit(0);
            }           

            dup2(fd1, 1); 
            close(fd1);
        }

        execvp (*args, args);
        perror("execvp");
        _exit(1);
        }

}

void cd (char *directory)
{
    char dir[BUF_SIZE] = {0};

    if (!directory) 
    {  
        directory = getenv ("HOME");

        if (chdir (directory))
            fprintf (stderr, "Failed to enter directory: %s\n", directory);
        else
            printf ("%s\n", directory);

        return;
    }

    if (*directory == '~') 
    { 
        strcpy (dir, getenv ("HOME"));
        strcat (dir, "/");
        strcat (dir, directory + 2);

        if (chdir (dir))
            fprintf (stderr, "Failed to enter directory: %s\n", dir);
        else
            printf ("%s\n", dir);

        return;
    }

    if (chdir (directory)) 
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to enter directory: %s\n", directory);
    else
        printf ("%s\n", directory);
}

int killpid (char *pidstr, int sig)
{
    pid_t pid = (pid_t)atoi (pidstr);

    if (pid < 1) 
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: requested pid < 1, ignoring\n");
        return (int)pid;
    }

    printf (" killing pid '%d' with signal '%d'\n", (int)pid, sig);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++ or something else?

Comment: Replace the `execvp(...)` with `int c; while((c = getchar()) != EOF) putchar(c);` and edit your question with the result.

Comment: It is C, I'm sorry msw my college server is down atm so I cannot I run it, but how would that work? It would print the files content but would not execute commands..Than my output wouldn't work. I have to be able to do "ls -al > out.txt" which works, but "sort < out.txt" does not give any outcome.

Comment: When setting up the `args[]` array, the last entry must contain NULL,  However, in the posted code, that only happens if the line read from the user contains either a `<` or a `>`.

Comment: the posted code contains special functionality for `cd`, `kill`, and `dir`  however there is no check in the code for `dir`, so that functionality will never be accessible to the user.

Comment: have you ran a debugger on the code to assure that the code block beginning with: ` if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0)` gets executed when the line from the user contains a `<`?

Comment: when opening a file for read, there should not be a `mode` parameter as the file 'should' already exist and have its' own 'mode' already defined. suggest modifying this statement: `if ((fd0 = open(input, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0)` to this: `if ((fd0 = open(input, O_RDONLY)) < 0)`

Comment: the line from the user could contain `>>` for an append to the output file.  That is not handled in the posted code.    the line from the user could contain: `2>&1` for placing both stderr and stdout to the same file.  That is not handled in the posted code.  There are several other common I/O redirection sequences that are not handled in the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a `<` in the args array here

```
if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0)
```

you set args[i] to `NULL`

```
    args[i]=NULL;
```

But then, you pass it to `strcmp()`

```
if(strcmp(args[i],">")==0)
```

and your child process will happily segfault. Use an `if-else`-construct here:

```
if(strcmp(args[i],"<")==0) {        
    args[i]=NULL;
    strcpy(input,args[i+1]);
    in=2;           
} else if(strcmp(args[i],">")==0) {      
    args[i]=NULL;
    strcpy(output,args[i+1]);
    out=2;
}
```

This should fix the error.

Furthermore, this might come in handy to detect such situations:

```
...
while (wait (&status) != pid)
     continue;
if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
     printf("Killed by signal %d%s\n",
            WTERMSIG(status), WCOREDUMP(status)?" (Core dumped)":"");
```

Comment: You've hit on a problem (not necessarily the only problem), but the 'set argument to null' means that the shell command will ignore any subsequent arguments.  In POSIX shells, you can write "`< input > output command-name arg1 arg2`" with the I/O redirection at arbitrary points in the input line (so "`> output command-name 2>/dev/null arg1 < input arg2`" works too). Unless all the I/O redirection is after the last command argument, zapping the argument pointer loses arguments to the command (in extreme cases, loses the command). The redirection args need to be removed and others shuffled down.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Since the loop is not terminated, it _will_ find a subsequent output redirection as far as I can see. Ok, you mean that regular arguments after a redirection are ignored. This is true, but I would say that this behaviour is at the shell designers disposition.

Comment: Yes, the shell will find it, but the `execvp()` will stop processing the command line at the first null pointer; it won't look for extra arguments after that.  So, if you have `command-name < input arg1 arg2`, the kernel won't pass `arg1` or `arg2` to the command.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Finally..I feel like a retard now haha. Oh I see, so I can only use one redirection per line and one argument.. That's okay for a start.